# Memory limit for process

Tags: android, linux, windows, memory-management

A friend and I have created an .jpg of size 30000x60000x3 that takes 7MB and it should take around 21.6GB of memory once uncompressed (30000x60000x3x4 = 2.16*10^10 bytes).

We have made a few tests with this in two computers and in two mobile phones:

- **Laptop**:  Xubuntu 16.04 x64, 12GB of RAM
- **Desktop**: Windows 7 x64,     6GB of RAM
- **Phone 1**: Android 2.3.6,     Samsung GT-S5830i
- **Phone 2**: Android 5.0.2,     Moto E (2nd generation)

We expected all the devices to run out of memory when opening the image but this is what happened:

- **Laptop**: It took up to 11GB of physical memory, we checked and `ulimit -m` which says `unlimited` and we set `vm.overcommit_memory = 2` and it still didn't run out of memory, it did slow down the computer but it did not block it. And couldn't open the image.
- **Desktop**: It stopped eating memory when the physical memory was at 5.7GB. And couldn't load the image.
- **Phone 1**: It does not open, but it does not freeze nor slow down the phone.
- **Phone 2**: It opens the image with no problem, very fast (~5 seconds).

We are wondering which safety methods are working in each of the operative systems, how could we disable them for testing purposes and why the Android devices can work better with the image than the other computers.

Comment: In short: [Virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). I don't see how *Phone 1* works better with the image than other devices. If functionality doesn't matter to you, it is trivial to optimize this to using zero resource.